# ¿Cuál es la concordancia de género apropiada?

Tags: género, concordancia-gramatical

En la oficina tenemos un jefe, y a una compañera le he dicho:

"Él va a seguir siendo jefe tuyo"

Ante lo que me ha surgido la duda, al ser "jefe de ti" ¿debería decirse "jefe tuya"?, ya que "ti" en este caso sería femenino.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

¿Quién es el jefe? --> Él

Tuyo es un adjetivo posesivo que denota al sujeto de la oración, luego al ser Él el sujeto de la misma, el adjetivo debe aplicarse sobre éste.

El modo correcto es "Él va a seguir siendo jefe tuyo", y si quieres evitar este tipo de problemas mejor "Él va a seguir siendo tu jefe". ;)

Con una jefa: "Ella va a seguir siendo jefa tuya", "Ella va a seguir siendo tu jefa".

Lo mismo pasaría con otros adjetivos posesivos como mío/mía "Ella va a seguir siendo jefa mía" "Él va a seguir siendo jefe mío", date cuenta que lo que importa es el sexo del sujeto, da igual cual sea mi sexo en las dos frases anteriores porque lo que denota el adjetivo es el sexo del sujeto.

Comment: Puedes editar y añadir un ejemplo con una jefa.

Comment: «Le dije al jefe tuyo que te dejara salir temprano.»  Como adjetivo que es, la palabra «tuyo(a)» no concuerda (necesariamente) con el sujeto (en mi ejemplo «yo») sino con el sintagma nominal al que pertenece, en este ejemplo el objeto indirecto («al jefe tuyo»).

Comment: Cierto... el adjetivo puede aplicarse sobre distintas partes de la oración, no exclusivamente sobre el sujeto, si bien en la frase de ejemplo sí adjetiva el sujeto.

Comment: Y supongo que también sería aceptable decir: "Ella va a seguir siendo jefe tuyo" (pues "jefe" es de género común, aunque admita también "jefa"), así como diríamos: "Ella va a seguir siendo superior tuyo". ¿No?

Comment: Así es... como bien ha hecho referencia en el comentario anterior Carlos, el adjetivo se aplica sobre el objeto indirecto, por tanto si aplicamos el género neutro sobre éste su adjetivación debería ir en el mismo género.